# Proxy Auto Config - Javascript Windows Environment Variable

Tags: javascript, proxy

I am trying to write a PAC file which can read a Windows Environment Variable that is set by GPO (e.g. ENABLE_PROXY = FALSE/TRUE)

Based on whether this Variable is true or not will either return a correct proxy server (uk-proxy-01:80) or a localhost (localhost:80)

I have read references online that say a PAC file is just javascript code. My google searching hasn't returned anything that works.

All I essentially want is:

```
    if ( ENABLE_PROXY == "TRUE" ){
    return "PROXY uk-proxy-01:80";
    else }
    return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:80";
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the environmental variable:

```
var result = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("SYSTEM")("ENABLE_PROXY");
if (result === "TRUE") {
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but unfortunately the code doesn't appear to work - I am testing it explicitly in the Opera Browser.